# Unity3D AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath() vs Resource.Load()

Tags: unity-game-engine

My partner in game dev are looking at Unity. I dynamically loaded an asset using Resource.Load() and he used AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(). They both seem to work so which one should be used? Why have 2 different ways to dynamically load assets?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath()` vs `Resource.Load()` ...They both
>   seem to work so which one should be used?

None of them.

Your partner will end up with a game that he cannot build because he used `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath()`. The `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath()` function came from the `UnityEditor` namespace which is only used to make Editor plugins. It won't work outside the Editor and it won't even let you build your game at-all.

You using `Resource.Load` is fine but `Resource.Load` requires the use of the Resources folder which is known to cause slow down loading time of the game.

---

AssetBundles is the recommended way. You can put those files in the *StreamingAssets* folder then use the `WWW` or `AssetBundle` API to load it during run-time. You can learn more about how to use AssetBundles [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/temas/best-practices/assetbundle-usage-patterns)