# How can my custom SRP doesn't get built in the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, render, compute-shader

I am trying to create my own custom scriptable render pipeline from scratch, using Core RP Library. For now, it's just rendering the colors (normalized maybe?) using the ray cast from the camera. Here is the video of [my render pipeline](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e2BQdX0HYJnqnBSvYjISFH8Dx_ykMTsl/view). Render loop is doing just one pass. But the built game is not rendering that colors. What could be possibly go wrong? What did I miss?

I think this should be good for the built game to do the render pass. Here is my render pipeline code:

```
public class MyRenderPipeline : RenderPipeline
{
    public CommandBuffer buffer;
    public ComputeShader shader;
    public RenderTexture texture;

    protected override void Render(ScriptableRenderContext context, List<Camera> cameras) {
        if (buffer == null) { buffer = new CommandBuffer { name = "Test" }; }
        if (shader == null ) {
            shader = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<ComputeShader>("Assets/System/DevPipeline/Graphics/ComputeRayTracing/RayTracingPass.compute");
        }
        if (texture == null || texture.width != Screen.width || texture.height != Screen.height) {
            if (texture != null) { texture.Release(); }
            texture = new RenderTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height, 0, RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat, RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear);
            texture.enableRandomWrite = true;
            texture.Create();
        }
        foreach (var camera in cameras) {
            context.SetupCameraProperties(camera);
            buffer.BeginSample(buffer.name);
            context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(buffer);
            buffer.Clear();

            buffer.SetComputeTextureParam(shader, 0, "Result", texture);
            buffer.SetComputeMatrixParam(shader, "CameraToWorld", camera.cameraToWorldMatrix);
            buffer.SetComputeMatrixParam(shader, "CameraInverseProjection", camera.projectionMatrix.inverse);
            buffer.DispatchCompute(shader, 0, Mathf.CeilToInt(Screen.width / 8.0f), Mathf.CeilToInt(Screen.height / 8.0f), 1);
            buffer.Blit(texture, camera.targetTexture);

            buffer.EndSample(buffer.name);
            context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(buffer);
            buffer.Clear();

            context.Submit();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think the compute shader code really needs to be shown, it's just a simple code. Not a big deal.

Comment: `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath` comes from the `UnityEditor` namespace and only works in editor code, it won't work at runtime. Instead use `Resource.Load` or AssetBundles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106849/unity3d-assetdatabase-loadassetatpath-vs-resource-load